# jsTree with dnd no dragged and locked nodes

Tags: drag-and-drop, jstree, drag, locked

I use jsTree library (ver. 3.1.1) with the dnd plugin.

In my tree i have two classes for no_dragging und locked.
It means -
no_dragging = the node can not dragged
locked = dragged node can not place on this node

But i have no idea how can i say jstree this node is not for dragging oder locked.
See the Code

```
$('#jstree1').jstree('destroy').jstree({
            'core' : {
                'check_callback' : true,
                'multiple' : false
            },
            "dnd": {
                'copy': false   
            },
            'plugins' : [ 'types', 'dnd' ],
            'types' : {
               //the types

            }
        });

        $(document)
        .on('dnd_start.vakata.jstree', function (e, data) {
            if($(data.element).closest('li').hasClass("no_dragging")){
                //no_dragging for this node
                //????
            }
        })
        .on('dnd_move.vakata', function (e, data) {
            var t = $(data.event.target);
            if(!t.closest('li').hasClass("locked")) {
              data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
            }
            else {
              data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
              //dont move the node in this node
              //???? 
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `dnd_start` event - it fires when you are already moving a node.
If you want to prevent dragging use the `is_draggable` [config option](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=dnd.is_&f=$.jstree.defaults.dnd.is_draggable):

```
is_draggable : function (nodes) {
    var i = 0, j = nodes.length;
    for(; i < j; i++) {
       if(this.get_node(nodes[i], true).hasClass('no_dragging')) {
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Preventing a node from being dropped on a parent is another deal - use the `core.check_callback` config option as a function, which you have now set to `true`.

```
check_callback : function (op, node, parent, position, more) {
    if((op === 'move_node' || op === 'copy_node') && parent.li_attr.class && parent.li_attr.class.indexOf('locked') !== -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/512/